# method (getElementsByClassName ) to get links

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

[https://docs.npmjs.com/][1]
// for get links

```
let items = document.getElementsByClassName('Box-sc-1b6inku-0 jVPEnE');
let data = [].map.call(items, item => item.innerText);
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

how to get full links
for example the first link: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use getElementsByTagName("a") to get all  then get their href attribute.

```
    let nodes = []
let items = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
  if(items[i].className === 'Box-sc-1b6inku-0 jVPEnE'){
     nodes.push(items[i])
  } 
}
let data = [].map.call(nodes, item => item.getAttribute("href"));
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ingenious_Hans Thank you for your answer, it's working but getElementsByTagName get all links not only the one with the specific class 'Box-sc-1b6inku-0 jVPEnE'

Comment: @stepstep i have edited

Comment: Ingenious_Hans Thank you so much for your help I appreciate it 
it's not working, mybe cause i run it in google chrome console.
if there is another way to get links from a one page
and only via getElementsByClassName cause sometime there is no 'a' tag in some page

Comment: This one works even in console